# WordCount on KV<String, String> counting words on value and preserving link to the key?

Tags: apache-beam

When reading some of the Beam examples I was wondering if there's a way to WordCount on values and preserve the key? Make those counts associated to the key so that bound is not lost.

Trying to modify the WordCount example I tried something as follows:

```
  public static class CountWords
      extends PTransform<PCollection<KV<String, String>>, PCollection<KV<String, KV<String, Long>>>> {
    @Override
    public PCollection<KV<String, Long>> expand(PCollection<KV<String, String>> items) {

      // Convert lines of text into individual words.
      PCollection<String> words = lines.apply(ParDo.of(new ExtractWordsFn()));

      // Count the number of times each word occurs.
      PCollection<KV<String, KV<String, Long>>> wordCounts = words.apply(Count.perElement());

      return wordCounts;
    }
  }
```

Still can't wrap my head around this and see how I could perform the count while keeping the link to the key.

The output I would like to have is, having the input `KV(string_key_1, some random text)`, get a KV output of `KV(string_key_1, KV({some: 1, random: 1, text: 1})`.

Is there a way to link a PCollection to a certain key and have it separately processed so it's still processed as in the example (PCollection>String)?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand what you want to do, I guess you want to do a Word Count on each key separately. If that's the case, this would work:

```
    final List<KV<String, String>> elements = Arrays.asList(
            KV.of("key1", "some random text"),
            KV.of("key1", "some different text"),
            KV.of("key1", "another random line"),
            KV.of("key2", "some random text different"),
            KV.of("key2", "bla bla bla")
    );

    p
            .apply("Create Elements", Create.of(elements))
            .apply("New combined KVs", ParDo.of(new DoFn<KV<String, String>, KV<String, Integer>>() {
                @ProcessElement
                public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
                    String[] values = c.element().getValue().split(" ");
                    for (String s: values) {
                        String key = String.format("%s %s", c.element().getKey(), s);
                        c.output(KV.of(key, 1));
                    }
                }
            }))
            .apply(Count.perKey())
            .apply("Separate KVs", ParDo.of(new DoFn<KV<String, Long>, KV<String, KV<String, Long>>>() {
                @ProcessElement
                public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
                    String[] keys = c.element().getKey().split(" ");
                    KV<String, Long> value = KV.of(keys[1], c.element().getValue());
                    c.output(KV.of(keys[0], value));
                }
            }))
            .apply(GroupByKey.create())
            .apply("LOG", ParDo.of(new DoFn<KV<String, Iterable<KV<String, Long>>>, String>() {
                @ProcessElement
                public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
                    LOG.info(c.element().toString());
                }
            }));
```

The output is

```
KV{key1, [KV{line, 1}, KV{text, 2}, KV{another, 1}, KV{different, 1}, KV{some, 2}, KV{random, 2}]}

KV{key2, [KV{different, 1}, KV{some, 1}, KV{bla, 3}, KV{text, 1}, KV{random, 1}]}
```

The general idea behind is that you combine the keys into "double keys" (i.e., `key1, some`, `key`, random`) and aggregate first. Then separate and group.